# Algorithm to decompose a number into the product of an integer and a base two exponencial

Tags: prime-numbers, primary-decomposition

So i`ve been asked to code an algorithm that decomposes an integer into the product of a base two exponencial and some integer.Something like **number = k.(2^n)** , k and n being random integers with k restricted to being odd.

---

My question is not about the programming aspect of this problem but rather the algebraic one as i have failed to came up with a standard procedure into finding one.The problem says thats the combination **k.(2^n)** is unique for every integer, so i`ve managed to find the combinations for certian numbers but it gets exponencially dificult as the number increases.

---

For example, **given the number 12** the only possible combination under this restrictions is **12 = 3(2^2)**

---

Please feel free to edit and improve anything you feel necessary as english is not my mother language

Comment: Write the integer in binary and count the number of zeros at the right-hand end

Comment: The problem says that $k \cdot 2^n$ is unique for every integer, but $4 = 1 \cdot 2^2$, and $4 = 4 \cdot 2^0$, so there must be something more about the representation that you haven't told us.

Comment: Just as a wild guess: perhaps $n \ge 0$, and $k$ is odd, and the input numbers are all nonzero (or perhaps even positive).

Comment: So your problem is " given a number M, find integers $v_1, v_2$ such that $M=v_12^{v_2} $. Is the given number integer?

Comment: Um.  Just keep dividing by 2 until what's left is an odd number.

Comment: "so i`ve managed to find the combinations for certian numbers but it gets exponencially dificult as the number increases."  How so?  Do the power of $2$ first, so you go from $M \to 2M' \to 2^2M''\to... $ until you get $2^kM'''''$ and $M''''''$ is odd.  It's a straight shot.

Comment: As fleeblood said, divide by 2 and count the number of times $x$ it works. When $\frac{n_{x+1}}{2}\ne \lfloor\frac{n_{x+1}}{2}\rfloor$ don't count that time. Use that factor, before the divide, as $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with $M$.  If $M$ is odd you are done.

If $M$ is even, let $M_1 =\frac M{2}$ and you have $2^1*M_1$.

If $M_1$ is odd you are done.  Otherwise let $M_2 = \frac {M_1}{2}$ and you have $2^2*M_2$.

Repeat.  Each step you will have $2^j*M_j$ and so long as $M_j$ is even you will continue to $M_{j+1} = \frac {M_j}2$ and have $2^{j+1}M_{j+1}$.

Eventually this will end you reach an odd $M_k$ and have $2^kM_k$.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to start with the $k$ you are given and $n=0$.  Then divide $k$ by $2$ as many times as possible, incrementing $n$ each time.

while $k$ is even
$\quad   k=k/2  $
$\quad   n=n+1$